# How make white on black text not bleed?

Tags: macos, mac, fonts

I have been in a lot of pain finding a good equivalent of notepad++ when switching to Mac, and I still miss it a lot because it features a lot of different keyword thanks to scintilla, which Smultron, Xcode and TextWrangler don't; example: int and for are colored the same, but they are not the same kind of statement. Even Xcode doesn't use enough keywords !

But I'm going to stop whining about those nerdish nightmares.

I configure my text editor to use bright text on a black background, and so far I use profont at 9pt, which is really much readable even at this really small size while being a bitmap font.

I wanted to switch to another TrueType font, Menlo or Inconsolata, but I went with some problem: the glyphs appear to "bleed" with white text on black background, it might be the algorithm OSX uses to draw fonts, but it looks like a bold typeface, and is less readable.

Is there any way to solve this problem ? Why can't I find any good scintilla-using editor on Mac?

What a big trouble for my nerdish sensitivity!

Answer (score 4):

In terms of the white text "bleeding" on a dark background; this is the aliasing at work. You want to turn on anti-aliasing for your text display. You can do it across the whole system by going to the Appearance Preference Pane in System Preferences and setting "Turn Off Text Smoothing for font sizes" to **9** or smaller.

In the specific applications you tried;

- TextWrangler: text smoothing is disabled at a certain point size defined in the preferences in the General section under Editing.
- Xcode: Only uses the system wide text smoothing options.

An alternative text editor I'd recommend checking out is TextMate as it has a very large community with bundles available to do your syntax hilighting and more.

As for an application that can leverage scintilla: [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) is available but the Mac port currently has no maintainer (hasn't made it past 1.79 on MacPorts - the current version is 2.2). There are some efforts to update it but none that are really shipping as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ can be run on Mac OS X with WINE

[image]

Comment: You just made my day! I thought I'd lost NP++ forever when switching to Ubuntu! How come I've never thought of WINE! Thanks!

Comment: @Blood you're most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

have you ever try [Editra](http://editra.org/)?

and also can run Notpad++ via [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxmac/)  in os x.